# Generador De Notas. ¿Como guardar en un TXT con su carpeta de usuario y mes?

Tags: javascript, php, html, txt

Bueno tengo este código pero en realidad me faltan bases lo hice funcionar hasta el copiado pero en el generador de guardar no me funciona la intención es que me guarde un archivo en .txt con el mes actual y cada que generen una nota guarden una información no toda solo algunos parámetros este seria un ejemplo de como quiero guardar el .txt

`[ 08/06/2021 | 02:46:47 p. m. | Cte: 12312 | Sin internet  | Navegación estable ]`

en el archivo actual cada que le den guardar le asigne una linea abajo de la que ya tienen guardada en el archivo.txt como dije que cada mes le de un nombre digamos Junio todo el mes de junio genere el guardado en ese archivo y en consecuencia el mes que viene y a si tal cual.

el generador son otros parámetros pero realidad solo me interesaría guardar los valores de Fecha, Hora, Contrato, Opcion1, Opcion6

adjunto el codigo que tengo hasta el momento

```html
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
<center><p><b><h1>Generador De Notas Softv.</h1></b>
<p><input type="text" name="contrato" placeholder="Contrato" required>
<p><input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Telefono" pattern="[6789][0-9]{9}" required>
 <p><select  name="Opcion1"  value="Opcion1" required><option value="">Tipo De LLamada:</option><option>Sin Internet</option><option>Internet Lento</option><option>Internet Inestable</option><option>Cambiar Contraseña</option><option>Red Abierta</option><option>Cambio De IP Publica</option><option>Cliente En Morosos</option><option>Reporte De Sucursal</option></select>
    <select  name="Opcion2"  value="Opcion2" required><option value="">Estado De La MAC:</option><option>Reg (05mb)</option><option>Reg (10mb)</option><option>Reg (20mb)</option><option>Reg (30mb)</option><option>Reg (50mb)</option></select>
  <p><select  name="Opcion3"  value="Opcion3" required><option value="">Estado Del Equipo:</option><option>Modem (On-Line)</option><option>Modem (Off-Line)</option><option>Moden (Init)</option><option>Modem (Reject)</option><option>Modem No Reg CMTS</option><option>Onu (On-Line)</option><option>Onu (On-Line Con Desconexiones)</option><option>Onu (Fibra Dañada)</option><option>Onu (Off-Line)</option><option>Antena (Off-Line)</option><option>Antena (On-Line)</option><option>Antena (Intermitente)</option></select>
    <select  name="Opcion4"  value="Opcion4" required><option  value="">Estado De Niveles:</option><option>Niveles OK</option><option>Niveles Altos</option><option>Niveles Bajos</option><option>Niveles Sin Registro</option><option>Niveles DW Altos</option><option>Niveles DW Bajos</option><option>Niveles UP Altos</option><option>Niveles UP Bajos</option><option>SNR Inestable</option></select>
  <p><select  name="Opcion5"  value="Opcion5" required><option value="">Soporte Aplicado:</option><option>Soporte Fisico Y Remoto</option><option>Se Aplica Configuración Solicitada</option><option>Se valida Pago y Se Activa Serv</option><option>Se Configura Sectorial</option><option>Se Activa ONU</option><option>Nateo de IP</option><option>Se Asesora Para Configurar EQ</option></select>
  <select  name="Opcion6"  value="Opcion6" required><option value="">Solucion Validada:</option><option>Navegación OK</option><option>Navegación estable</option><option>Navegación no estable</option><option>Navegación lenta</option><option>Servicio reactivado</option><option>Equipo no responde </option><option>Led Wifi no enciende</option><option>Se regresará llamada</option><option>Cte no contesta</option><option>Se corta llamada</option><option>Eq sin acceso remoto</option></select>
  <p><input type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="Restaurar">   <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generar Nota">  
</center>
<?php 
     echo '<script src="https://norfipc.com/js/clipboard.min.js"></script>'; 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo "<center></br><p id='codigo'>" . $_POST['contrato'] . " | " . $_POST['telefono'] . " | " . $_POST['Opcion1'] . " | " . $_POST['Opcion2'] . " | " . $_POST['Opcion3'] . " | " . $_POST['Opcion4'] . " | " . $_POST['Opcion5'] . " | " . $_POST['Opcion6'] . "</p></center>";
echo "</br>";
echo "<center><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='copyClip' data-clipboard-target='#codigo'>Copiar Nota</button> <button type='button' class='btn btn-info' id='txt' name='submit'>Gaurdar Archivo</button></center>";
}
    if (isset($_POST['txt'])) {
      $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
      echo $_POST['date'];
      echo $_POST['contrato'];
      echo $_POST['Opcion1'];
      echo $_POST['Opcion6'];

      $myfile = fopen("Junio.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file");
      $date = $_POST['date']."\n";
      $contrato = $_POST['contrato']."\n";
      $Opcion1 = $_POST['Opcion1']."\n";
      $Opcion6 = $_POST['Opcion6']."\n";
      fwrite($myfile, $date);
      fclose($myfile);
    }
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Tal vez quieras mejorar el título, porque la respuesta a la pregunta *"Cómo puedo crear un botón para guardar"*, es tan simple como `<button type="submit"></button>` dentro del `<form/>`

Comment: a ver si ahora es mas entendible, en fin la cuestión es que tengo 7 usuarios que usan un sistema de web creado apartir de codigo simple en php y html la idea es que ellos generan a diario notas y quisiera que al final las guardaran y descargaran para tenr un registro del trabajo diario.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno ya lo pude solucionar Igual se agradece sus comentarios, por si alguno es gustoso les dejo el código ya con la solucion.

```html
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
<center><p><b><h1>Generador De Notas Softv</h1></b>
<p><input type="text" name="contrato" placeholder="Contrato" required>
<p><input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Telefono" pattern="[6789][0-9]{9}" required>
 <p><select  name="Opcion1"  value="Opcion1" required><option value="">Tipo De LLamada:</option><option>Sin Internet</option><option>Internet Lento</option><option>Internet Inestable</option><option>Cambiar Contraseña</option><option>Red Abierta</option><option>Cambio De IP Publica</option><option>Cliente En Morosos</option><option>Reporte De Sucursal</option></select>
    <select  name="Opcion2"  value="Opcion2" required><option value="">Estado De La MAC:</option><option>Reg (05mb)</option><option>Reg (10mb)</option><option>Reg (20mb)</option><option>Reg (30mb)</option><option>Reg (50mb)</option></select>
  <p><select  name="Opcion3"  value="Opcion3" required><option value="">Estado Del Equipo:</option><option>Modem (On-Line)</option><option>Modem (Off-Line)</option><option>Moden (Init)</option><option>Modem (Reject)</option><option>Modem No Reg CMTS</option><option>Onu (On-Line)</option><option>Onu (On-Line Con Desconexiones)</option><option>Onu (Fibra Dañada)</option><option>Onu (Off-Line)</option><option>Antena (Off-Line)</option><option>Antena (On-Line)</option><option>Antena (Intermitente)</option></select>
    <select  name="Opcion4"  value="Opcion4" required><option  value="">Estado De Niveles:</option><option>Niveles OK</option><option>Niveles Altos</option><option>Niveles Bajos</option><option>Niveles Sin Registro</option><option>Niveles DW Altos</option><option>Niveles DW Bajos</option><option>Niveles UP Altos</option><option>Niveles UP Bajos</option><option>SNR Inestable</option></select>
  <p><select  name="Opcion5"  value="Opcion5" required><option value="">Soporte Aplicado:</option><option>Soporte Fisico Y Remoto</option><option>Se Aplica Configuración Solicitada</option><option>Se valida Pago y Se Activa Serv</option><option>Se Configura Sectorial</option><option>Se Activa ONU</option><option>Nateo de IP</option><option>Se Asesora Para Configurar EQ</option></select>
  <select  name="Opcion6"  value="Opcion6" required><option value="">Solucion Validada:</option><option>Navegación OK</option><option>Navegación estable</option><option>Navegación no estable</option><option>Navegación lenta</option><option>Servicio reactivado</option><option>Equipo no responde </option><option>Led Wifi no enciende</option><option>Se regresará llamada</option><option>Cte no contesta</option><option>Se corta llamada</option><option>Eq sin acceso remoto</option></select>
  <p><input type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="Restaurar">  <form><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generar Nota"></form>  
</center>
</form>
<?php 
     echo '<script src="https://norfipc.com/js/clipboard.min.js"></script>'; 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo "<center></br><form><p id='codigo'>" . $_POST['contrato'] . " | " . $_POST['telefono'] . " | " . $_POST['Opcion1'] . " | " . $_POST['Opcion2'] . " | " . $_POST['Opcion3'] . " | " . $_POST['Opcion4'] . " | " . $_POST['Opcion5'] . " | " . $_POST['Opcion6'] . "</p></form></center>";
echo "</br>";

echo "<center><form><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='copyClip' data-clipboard-target='#codigo'>Copiar Nota</button></form><form><button type='button' id='button1' class='btn btn-info'>Gaurdar Archivo</button></form></center>";

$contrato= $_REQUEST["contrato"];
$opcion1= $_REQUEST["Opcion1"];
$opcion6= $_REQUEST["Opcion6"];
$MiNick = $_SESSION['username'];
$dias = array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
$meses = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
$fechita = $dias[date('w')]." ".date('d')." de ".$meses[date('n')-1]. " del ".date('Y');
$elmes = $meses[date('n')-1];
$dir = "$MiNick";
if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    if (false === @mkdir($dir, 0777, true)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Fallo al crear el directorio $MiNick', $dir));
    }
  }
$myFile = "$MiNick/$elmes.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a+') or die("No se encontro ningun archivo");
$hora = date('h:i:s A');
$stringData = "[ $fechita | $hora | $contrato | $opcion1 | $opcion6 ]\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
}
?>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $('#button1').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "Notas.php",
 data: "",
 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("No se pudo conectar con el servidor");
 }
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

para que el puntero este al final pones esto fopen("Junio.txt", "a"), los datos los puedes poner en una array y recorrerlos con un for.

Comment: es que no entiendo mucho como comente arriba es lo básico, de igual manera quisiera que tomara esos datos que quiero solamente y los guarde con el nombre de usuario que esta logeado y les genere una carpeta y vaya poniendo las lineas en el txt no soy muy experto y no entiendo mucho de codigos apenas estoy entrando en el mundo de la programacion de web y nuestra página apenas duras esta en un codigo muy simple gracias.

Comment: Vale cambia pon este fopen("Junio.txt", "a"), para las variables concatena seria algo asi $data =  $_POST['date'] . $_POST['contrato']. $_POST['Opcion1'] . $_POST['Opcion6']  ; asi tendrias todas las variables en data, y aqui se guardarian  fwrite($myfile, $date);. Espero te sirva me comentas

Comment: ya lo intente pero no funciono igual voy a seguir leyendo como hacerlo y si lo logro muestro el código final ya funcionando.